# How to get back data (backup stored in Google account) after factory resetting Samsung Galaxy Note 4?

Tags: restore

Before factory resetting the device, I made backup in my Gmail ID.  But now I can't find the backup option.

Is there any way to recover the data?  If it's possible, how can I do this?

Comment: Did you sign back into your Gmail account during the first boot setup?

Comment: yes i did.  but i can't find the option of recovering all my data.  what should i do?? @MatthewRead

Comment: What data are you referring too? Cause I had the Note 4 and would do a factory reset every time, I flashed a new ROM and I always kept my pictures and etc. If you are referring to app data... Good luck. Google claims to backup the app and its data. But I have never had that work for me. I also learned that the hard way many years ago. That's why I always root my device and install Titanium Backup, there are non-root options, but at the time I was learning about TB, There wasn't and it just kind of stuck over the years. =p

Answer (score 1):

in spite of the popup which says to avoid asking for clarification,
i need to ask for clarification.

What type of data. Where is/was it stored?

Reason 1 - if you are talking about sent messages and drafts gmail should store that automatically. check your folders @gmail.

Reason 2 - if this is "deleted" data on device then you have a data recovery possible by cross-compiling the foremost forensic data recovery tool for usage on your device. I have actually done this before. Though foremost is a little limited it what it can retrieve. You do not necessarily need root access in normal operation to use it if you have a custom recovery.

If you do have a custom recovery first dump the entire data partition via adb shell, usually cwm/twrp both have parted available, you will need to find out what your block device layout is, assuming it's an mmcblk type, while in recovery and connected via adb run

```
adb shell
parted /dev/block/mmcblk0
```

[or the like, and at (parted) prompt run]

```
print all
```

then number along the left column corresponds to the mmcblk partition. So if userdata show up at entry 18 for example, then your data partition is

```
/dev/block/mmcblk0p18
```

once you find that out back out of adb shell to your regular terminal prompt
and run, using example above , your specifics will vary,

```
adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p18 data.img
```

from there you have an emrgency backup of the data partition that you can take to someone else to perform the data recovery procedure if you can't manage it yourself.

From here you can push foremost to your device after mounting /system and /data

```
adb shell mount /system && adb shell mount /data
```

and run through the routine, alternately you can mount the data partion image you pulled and try the available foremost build for your distro.